# JavaScript form validation on client side, for an form made with a random script

Tags: random, webforms, jquery-validate

I am doing a webapp for my iPad to help my son with his math.

Every time you reload the page, it gives you a new test. What I am missing is the client-side validation. I've used jQuery before but never for something random. 
Here is a small piece of the code that creates the random string for the questions.

The problem is that I have no way to validate the answers on real time.

```
<tbody><tr> 
    <td><li class="smallfield"><span class="name"><script language="JavaScript">
<!--
var r_text = new Array ();
r_text[0] = "1 x 1 =";
r_text[1] = "1 x 2 =";
r_text[2] = "1 x 3 =";
r_text[3] = "1 x 4 =";
r_text[4] = "1 x 5 =";
r_text[5] = "1 x 6 =";
r_text[6] = "1 x 7 =";
r_text[7] = "1 x 8 =";
r_text[8] = "1 x 9 =";
r_text[9] = "1 x 10 =";
r_text[10] = "1 x 11 =";
r_text[11] = "1 x 12 =";;

var i = Math.floor(12*Math.random())

document.write(r_text[i]);

//-->
</script></span><input placeholder="=" type="num" />
            </li></td>
    <td><li class="smallfield"><span class="name"><script language="JavaScript">
<!--
var r_text = new Array ();
r_text[0] = "1 x 1 =";
r_text[1] = "1 x 2 =";
r_text[2] = "1 x 3 =";
r_text[3] = "1 x 4 =";
r_text[4] = "1 x 5 =";
r_text[5] = "1 x 6 =";
r_text[6] = "1 x 7 =";
r_text[7] = "1 x 8 =";
r_text[8] = "1 x 9 =";
r_text[9] = "1 x 10 =";
r_text[10] = "1 x 11 =";
r_text[11] = "1 x 12 =";;

var i = Math.floor(12*Math.random())

document.write(r_text[i]);

//-->
</script></span><input placeholder="=" type="num" />
            </li></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, you would need save the question that you write out in a variable so that you can access it later. Something like:

```
var question = r_text[i];
document.write(question);
```

this way, you can use the value later.

However, this means that you have to extract the random number from the question string for validation. A better method, though, would probably be to simply save the generated random number (i) and write the question out like so

```
document.write("1 x " + i + " =");
```

eliminating the need for the r_text array.

Now, for validation, you could have a button next to the input fields and call a validation method using the onClick event.

```
<button onClick="javascript:validateAnswer()">Check!</button>
```

where validateAnswer would get the text in the input field and see if the answer is correct.